# Blender - Why is my Mesh not moving with my rig?

Tags: blender, mesh, 3d-modelling

I imported a .fbx model to blender and made a rig, which I want to attach to the mesh.
The problem is, that, after parenting, when I rotate the bones, the mesh is not moving with it.

The following links are a few screenshots to make it more clear, what I mean with some points.

What did I do so far:

- Imported [mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwR2x.png)
- Made mesh, which, in my opinion, does [fit the mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzAi4.png)
- Then I selected the mesh, shift-selected the rig and parented it with automatic weights.
- Then I have the stated problem.

In a youtube comment someone suggested to parent the rig "manually" to the mesh by selecting it as parent via [the object properties and setting it to armature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMa51.png).
This works SOMEHOW, but in a very weird way, the mesh is drawn in points which I dont want to draw [with the bones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdsYk.png).

What do I do wrong?
I appreciate the help. If you need more information or pictures, feel free to ask, I am not really sure, what is important and what not.

Comment: Update: I tried a simple mesh (cube "sliced" into subpieces) with 3 simple bones, and it works perfectly. Why is it not working with my imported object?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0):

The mesh moving like what you shown in the last picture is because of the weight painting. The bone will be attached to the mesh that is close to it, so since the arms in your mesh are not in a T-pose, they will be automatically attached to the tighs because they are somewhat close.

One way to go around this would be to pose your mesh in a t-pose. Another way could be to weight paint manually the points of the mesh to each bone (you would have absolute control of the mesh doing this) but that is very tedious in my opinion.

Or, have you ever tried using rigify to generate a rig based on that armature? It might be simpler to create the rig of your character. If you enable it on the add-ons panel, you can parent the generated rig to your mesh easily (but if your mesh is not in t-pose you could still have the problem of the body moving oddly).